# Sorting PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have three MySQL tables that I need to query for all of the rows. Upon getting all of the rows from each table, I need to create a multidimensional array whereby each index of that array contains only value from each of the tables. What I have right now works. But, something is telling me that there has got to be a better way of accomplishing this.

```
$tables = array('table_one', 'table_two', 'table_three');
$final = array();

foreach($tables as $table) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table."";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql)or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $i = 0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $id[$i] = $row['user_id'];

        $i++;
    }

    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) {
       if(!is_array($final[$i])) {
            $final[$i] = array($id[$i]);
       } else {
            array_push($final[$i], $id[$i]);
       }
    }
}
```

The end results is something that looks like this

```
$final = array(array('table_one_row_one_val', 'table_two_row_one_val', 'table_three_row_one_val'),
             array('table_one_row_two_val', 'table_two_row_two_val', 'table_three_row_two_val'),
             array('table_one_row_three_val', 'table_two_row_three_val', 'table_three_row_three_val')
         );
```

I get the gut felling that this could be done much more effectively, but I'm not sure how.

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: Make use of MySQL JOIN instead of selecting single tables three times. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html

Comment: Yes, but there isn't any commonality amongst the values of the rows in the tables

Comment: If there isn't any commonality, why are you fetching three tables? That's absolutely without logic.

Comment: It's not without logic. Just because there isn't any commonality amongst the values in the three tables doesn't mean that I need the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your code simpler if you make your query more explicit in selecting the columns you want in the order you want them. So for example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT table_one.user_id as u1, table_two.user_id as u2, table_three.user_id as u3 FROM ' . implode(',', $tables);
```

Then each row of your result set will have the columns in the proper order making the construction of your arrays less involved. For example:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql)or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $final[] = array($row['u1'], $row['u2'], $row['u3']);
}
```

There may be issues with the order and relationships of the data in these arrays (especially if all 3 tables don't have the same number of rows), but working just off the information above, this is another way you could approach it. Something to think about anyway.

Comment: This is terrible suggestion. What if these three tables has about 50K rows. This will knock out the server with this full join

Comment: bksi, no question. There are a lot of potential pitfalls here (as I noted) but the OP has that problem already. Knowing nothing about the environment or the data, it's impossible to recommend a better overall design. I was just answering the question as stated in the hope it'll give the OP something else to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'user_id' FROM ".$table;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
$tables = array('table_one', 'table_two', 'table_three');
$final = array();

foreach($tables as $tableIndex => $table) {
    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM ".$table;
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql)or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $i = 0;

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $final[$tableIndex][$i] = $row['user_id'];
        $i++;
    }
}
```

It is always better selecting only the columns you will use. SELECT * is not a good SQL practice.